# Convergence of the infinite product $\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{z - \alpha_n}{z - \beta_n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been trying to solve this homework problem for a while but I can't seem to get any significant ideas about how to approach it, so I would really appreciate any hints that could help me solve it.

The problem is exercise 8.14 from Steven Krantz and Robert Greene's book Function Theory of One Complex Variable. It goes as follows:

> Suppose that 
>   $$\sum |\alpha_n - \beta_n| < \infty$$
>   Then determine the largest open set of $z$ for which
>   $$\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{z - \alpha_n}{z - \beta_n}$$
>   converges normally.

What I've tried so far is writing the factors as

$$\frac{z - \alpha_n}{z - \beta_n} = 1 + \frac{z - \alpha_n}{z - \beta_n} - 1 = 1 + \frac{\beta_n - \alpha_n}{z - \beta_n}$$

so as to put the infinite product in the form $\displaystyle{\prod (1 + f_n(z))}$ to try to apply the basic convergence criteria I have available  which says that this product would converge normally if the series

$$\sum |f_n(z)|$$ 
converges normally. Now I'm kind of stuck here because I think that maybe I would have to bound this sum with the sum $\sum |\alpha_n - \beta_n|$ but I'm not sure about how to proceed (assuming that this is the right way to follow).

So I would really appreciate some hints that would get me in the right track to solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the product converges normally on any compact set $K\subset \mathbb{C}\setminus ((\beta_j)_j)$: With your notation, and using Hölder's inequality $\sum |f_n|_K \leq \sup_n |(\cdot-\beta_n)^{-1}|_K \sum |\alpha_n-\beta_n|$ and this implies the claim.

Comment: @Jose27 Can you please expand a little bit about what you wrote. I don't think I follow how to use Hölder's inequality here.

Comment: Well, $$\sum |f_n(z)| = \sum |(z-\beta_n)^{-1}||\alpha_n-\beta_n| \leq \sup_n |(z-\beta_n)^{-1}|\left(\sum |\alpha_n-\beta_n|\right)$$. This shows that, on $K$ as above, the sum converges compactly. Now just use the same argument with $|\cdot|_K$ replacing $|\cdot|$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose that $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\overline{\{b_n\}}$, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ so that $|z-b_n|\ge\epsilon$ for all $n$. Then,
$$
\sum_n\left|\frac{b_n-a_n}{z-b_n}\right|\le\frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_n|b_n-a_n|<\infty\tag{1}
$$
Inequality $(1)$ implies that
$$
\prod_n\frac{z-a_n}{z-b_n}=\prod_n\left(1+\frac{b_n-a_n}{z-b_n}\right)\tag{2}
$$
converges.

Comment: I had Steven Krantz for both complex analysis and fourier analysis when he was at UCLA around 1980. He is an excellent teacher, one of the few math professors to get a [Distinguished Teaching Award](http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/archive/catalog/2010-11/catalog/catalog10-11-830.htm#50638857_pgfId-320679) at UCLA.

Comment: @robjohn how is this answer different than the one i provided. I guess other than the fact, that the largest set you found was $C- sup of b_{n}$ am i missing something here ?

Comment: @robjohn should n't the open set be C- set of all values of $b_{n}$ ?

Comment: @Hardy: $\mathbb{C}\setminus\overline{\{b_n\}}$ is the complement of the closure of the sequence. We want to exclude limit points of $\{b_n\}$ as well.

Comment: @Hardy: your answer seems to assume that $\left|\frac{\beta_n - \alpha_n}{z - \beta_n}\right| < |\alpha_n - \beta_n|$, which is a difference.

Comment: @robjohn In the interest of anyone else wanting to submit anything they have been working on i 'll keep this bounty open but no one does i shall grant thee the bounty in due time.

Comment: @robjohn Suppose $\alpha_n=\beta_n$; then all of the factors in the product are identically $1$ and the largest open set where it converges is all of $\mathbb{C}$, regardless of what the sequence $(b_n)$ is. Is there any hypotheses over the sequences we may impose so that the largest domain is $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{\{b_n\}}$?

Comment: @robjohn After some thought, I think assuming $\alpha_n \neq \beta_n$ for all $n$ does the trick -- could you confirm? Thanks!

Comment: The product is not defined at any $z=b_n$; there are removable singularities at those points, so we *can* say that the function $1$ is equal everywhere but at $z=b_n$, but that is **not** the product.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are very close.

The convergence criteria you are using is correct - consider this:

We observe that

$$|\beta_n - \alpha_n| = |\alpha_n - \beta_n| $$

so 
$$\left|\frac{\beta_n - \alpha_n}{z - \beta_n}\right| < |\alpha_n - \beta_n| $$
As you know that the absolute series converges as per the question's definition so $$\sum \left|\frac{\beta_n - \alpha_n}{z - \beta_n}\right| \leqslant \sum |\alpha_n - \beta_n| < \infty$$ so it converges by limit comparison theorem.

As per the largest open set, the condition needed for convergence is $\left|\frac{\beta_n - \alpha_n}{z - \beta_n} \right| \leqslant |\alpha_n - \beta_n| $ Solve for $z$.

Comment: Why is $\left| \frac{\beta_n-\alpha_n}{z-\beta_n}\right| < |\alpha_n-\beta_n|$ necessary for convergence?

Comment: @Jose27 As the author points out to get convergence we need $$\sum |f_n(z)|$$ u can also refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product if you doubt that. Under the information provided the only way to make this happen is the above condition although it shoudl be greater than equals i 'll update it.

Comment: But a bound like $\left| \frac{\beta_n-\alpha_n}{z-\beta_n}\right| \leq C|\alpha_n-\beta_n|$ with $C$ not depending on $n$ would also ensure convergence (hence your condition is not necessary, only sufficient).

Comment: I guess i stand corrected u are right it should and the largest open set would be obtained when we solve for z and take the limit C goes to infinity

Comment: I guess what i do n't like about this is that we end up with $|\beta_{n}| <= |z|$ which seems not an elegant answer.